# Protect JSON from parsing

Tags: json, single-page-application

I'm evaluating a switch from MVC to a full SPA application for one of my projects, but I have doubts about sending all my data through JSON.

Let me explain better.

My project contains a lot of data that I carefully collected through years of work, and this data is at the core of my project. In my current MVC implementation I try to protect against scraping/crawling by randomly changing the structure of my page and setting other limits. I know this is not a perfect solution, but it works good.

My question is: if I switch to a full SPA application, one where data is requested from the client and downloaded as a JSON response, how can I protect this response from being parsed? It seems like JSON is very easy to parse, with a lot of tools already available. Someone could visit all my pages, use a client debugger to get response data and parse it with one of these tools. Am I wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You probably can't. Injected syntax errors will be easily corrected. As the client has to read it, encryption won't save you... But on the other hand: If someone really wanted your data, he could just parse it out the html too.

Comment: Then why switch to an SPA? In any case, you're sending data to the client, JSON or HTML, and both can be easily parsed and downloaded.